# Reading contents of a qcow2 image using `bdrv_pread(..)` or alternatives

Tags: c++, c, qemu, kvm

I wanted to read contents off a `.qcow2` image using `bdrv_pread(...)` functions in QEMU.
Say, the full path of my image is `/path/to/myimage.qcow2`, I want to be able to read 'n' bytes of data off of this image at a particular offset. Now the `bdrv_pread` functions takes these arguments '`BlockDriverState *bs, int64_t offset, void *buf, int count1`', how exactly do I initialize the `BlockDriverState` (device?) from the path of the image. All other parameters other than `BlockDriverState` are clear to me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your goal is to access a qcow2 file from your own program I would recommend not trying to use the QEMU functions.  These are going to have a lot of state associated with QEMU that is not necessary if all you want to do is read the contents of the qcow2 file.  Instead you could look at the [qcow2 specification](https://people.gnome.org/~markmc/qcow-image-format.html) or if you want to work at one higher level of abstraction you could look at the [libguestfs](http://libguestfs.org/) library, which states that it has an API for accessing the supported VM disk formats (although I have never used it myself).  There is some example code [here](http://libguestfs.org/guestfs-examples.3.html) that can help you get started.